# For "A New Perspective", Is the total First-Person time calculated between Campaign and Online?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v, grand-theft-auto-online

On Grand Theft Auto V, there is an Achievement/Trophy/Accomplishment called "A New Perspective" that requires you to play the game in First Person for 15 hours.

[image]

Is the total time calculated between GTA Online and the Campaign mode (example: 5 hours on campaign and 10 in online to get it) or I need to complete it on one of the two?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [this Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/RedditDads/comments/2ob5wj/a_new_perspective_play_gta_v_in_first_person_mode/cmlg9dd/) post:

> It accumulates between single player and online play overall, you don't need to play 15hrs in first person in one, continuous sitting.
>
> You check it by going into your pause menu > Stats > General > Time played in first person (2nd one from the top).

You can confirm it yourself (as I did before posting this answer) by checking the menu that is mentioned in the second paragraph.